# Accessing database live / without refreshing browser without AJAX

Tags: php, database

Is it possible? Say I have a small database consisting of:

Item - Type - StoreA - StoreB

Apple - Fruit - 5 - 6

Orange - Fruit - 3 - 4

Celery - Vegetable - 8 - 5

Given I have a page wherein I can buy any of the items listed (say 5 dropdowns of the same database listing and another set of dropdowns for store options), then I want to display the price beside it, is it possible without using AJAX/JS? If not, is there any quick code snippets on how I should use AJAX on this database?

Comment: why you should not use ajax?

Comment: I'm not fond of the whole js/ajax syntax. I "want/need" my site to be functional asap, and my learning for a new language might take time

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're gonna need some Ajax to do so.
Ajax will upload your datas without reloading the page, but still you will need to refresh the page to see any modification.

That's why you will also need to simulate the processing of datas with some Javascript.

Which means :

1. You will need to put the values you got from your SQL SELECT into JS variables or array
2. You will need a JS function that builds your array
3. Call back this function everytime you modify anything (except for  inputs, then you just need to set the focus on the current value)

```js
var datas = {
    NameOfVariable : YourInputID,
    NameOfVariable2 : YourInputID2,
    bJSON: 1,
    page: "your_destination_page_without_file_extension_name"
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your_main_php_file.php",
    async: false, /* or true as you wish, false is deprecated but useful */
    data: datas,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
}).done(function(result) {
    //The JS which simulates the data transfer
    //+ In the end, the function that builds your table
}).fail(function(err) {
    alert('error : ' + err.status);
});
```

Comment: In the example I gave, I put the price of the item under a textfield on .done right?

Comment: Not really.
First of all you should train yourself by recreating with Javascript the four main actions which are the core of SQL.
SELECT.
INSERT.
UPDATE.
DELETE.

In the .done function, you will put the code that simulates the needed action.

For example, if you want to exectue "DELETE FROM table WHERE (condition, could be "where item="Apple"). then you should try to do it first with Javascript. Hint : there is a "delete" built-in function in Javascript.